# T-test to test if sample comes from the same distribution?

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test

I have a small dataset, sample size of n = 25. These samples form a distribution that looks normally distributed, let's call this distribution Y. I also have a different sample let's call this sample x. Now I want to find out if x is significantly different from Y.

I want to find out if x comes from the same distribution as my other samples. I was thinking of using the t-test for this. Is this a reasonable assumption?

Example:

Y = [1000, 1100, 900, 1050, 920, 1200]

x = [300]

Q: Is x from the same distribution as Y?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83163/statistical-test-to-tell-whether-two-samples-are-pulled-from-the-same-population?rq=1

Comment: yes. see here: https://www.statisticssolutions.com/manova-analysis-one-sample-t-test/. if X is more than one sample then also t-test can be used